# how to copy files with extension .txt?

Tags: python, typeerror, file-copying

### I am trying create a program to automatizate  the creation of the files .txt of directory to my work in python.
I managed to create a code to find all the files with extension .txt . but but i can't copy all these files to another folder, because it shows me the following error.
I leave you my code, so that you can help me regarding the error that it shows me.

```
import pathlib
from datetime import date
from shutil import  copyfile

date_backup = date.today()
str_date_backup = str(date_backup).replace('-','.')

path_input = r'D:\2 PERSONAL'
ruta = pathlib.Path(path_input)
for archivo in ruta.glob("**\\*.txt"):
    path_out = r'D:\Backup' + '\\' + str_date_backup + " - " + archivo
    copyfile(path_input, path_out)
```

**The ERROR is:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\5 PROYECTOS PYTHON\Automatizar_Backup\Automatizar_Backup.py", line 24, in <module>
    path_out = r'D:\Backup' + '\\' + str_date_backup + " - " + archivo
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "WindowsPath") to str
```

Comment: You could have looked this up in the documentation.  To convert a `Path` to a string, just do `str(archivo)`.

Comment: @TimRoberts you shouldn't be doing that anyway, you should be using `/` to join a string (or other `pathlib.Path`) to a `pathlib.Path`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`OS.walk()` generates the file names in a directory tree by walking the tree either top-down or bottom-up. For each directory in the tree rooted at the directory top (including top itself), it yields a 3-tuple (dirpath, dirnames, filenames).

you can simply use this:

```
import os
from datetime import date
from shutil import copyfile
 

date_backup = date.today()
str_date_backup = str(date_backup).replace('-','.')

path_input = 'D:\\2 PERSONAL'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path_input):#dir_path
    for file in files: 
        # change the extension from '.txt' to 
        # the one of your choice.
        if file.endswith('.txt'):
            path_current = root+'/'+str(file)
            path_out = r'D:\Backup' + '\\' + str_date_backup + " - " + str(file)
            copyfile(path_current, path_out)
```

Comment: Wow, thank you very much.

This really works. ♥

Answer (score 0):

This happens because using glob on a [`pathlib.Path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path) object [yields all the files that match the pattern](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) (in your case, `"**\*.txt"`). Luckily, this is as easy as converting your `WindowsPath` (or `PosixPath` in other systems) to string:

```
for file in pathlib.Path(".").glob("*.txt"):
    file = str(file)
```